# Adding Apache Jena to an existing NetBeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, jena

I've opened an existing NetBeans project, and the developers have been using the Apache Jena framework. But they did not use Maven, and obviously NetBeans is complaining about inexistant `org.apache.jena.xxx` packages.

So I've downloaded Jena from [here](http://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi), and added it to the project with **Right click on `Libraries` > `Add JAR/Folder`** and selecting the unzipped Jena folder.

But NetBeans doesn't seem happy with that, since it's still not finding all of the `org.apache.jena.xxx` packages.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you downloaded, source or release. 
I assume you downloaded the release package. Unzip it somewhere (for example c:\mylibs\jena but you can choose any location)

Click on "*Libraries*" node in "*Projects*". In open dialogue click "*Create*".
Enter library name "**jena**" and add in tab "*Classpath*" all jar files in

```
c:\mylibs\jena\lib
```

Do the same for "*Sources*" tab (If you need source download Jena source and attach them to library)

In the end click "Add library" and your done (almost).

If Netbeans still can complains (you can see "*Source Packages*" in *Project* has red notification icon), you need to do a final setup. Check what is missing in classpath. It is easy to guess from import statement.

Using library functionality much easier to manipulate with project dependencies (not such comfortable as with maven but better then manual adjust for each project)

Comment: Ok, I have added Jena myself using your method. The different JARs have been added to the project, but Netbeans keeps complaining about missing classes and packages, even though they *are* in the library tree. Interestingly, when I try to add an `import` myself, the auto-completion engine recognizes `org.apache` but not `org.apache.jena`.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Jena uses maven as our build system. If you are you using maven the easiest way to consume Jena libraries is to add a dependency like so:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
  <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</groupId>
  <version>X.Y.Z</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Where `X.Y.Z` is the desired version, the latest being 3.1.0 at the time of writing

This will pull in a variety of the most commonly used Jena libraries. You may need to add additional dependencies if you're using additional features. You can find the current set of available libraries by searching on Maven central:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.jena%22

Comment: Unfortunately, the project I have doesn't use Maven. Is there a way to add Maven to an existing project?

Comment: Yes. Quick introduce yourself into maven default project structure (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).  Copy java files into corresponding folder. Then start to add dependency into pom.xml file. Any good IDE will help you if there is error in projects